# How to query the relation of series of activities triggered by users from SQL or NoSQL?

Tags: sql, database, select, nosql, time-series

Here is my table, which describe a user bought some items at some time.

```
time, user, item_id
```

my data:

```
100, u1, i1
150, u2, i2
200, u1, i2
300, u1, i3
450, u2, i5
```

the result I want is the items each users bought order by time:

```
u1, [i1, i2, i3]
u2, [i2, i5]
```

Is there a SQL query which can do this? If not, is there any other kind of database which is suitable for this requirement? Consider the data quantity could be huge, which solution can have best performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, SQL databases can produce these results.  Without specifying one, then your question is either too broad or you are asking for a recommendation -- both reasons to close a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are SQL Queries which can do that for an example in MYSQL you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` which will cater your requirement.

```
SELECT USER, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item_id ORDER BY time SEPARATOR ',')
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this if SQL SERVER(TSQL) is Used.

```
SELECT [user],
    abc = 
    STUFF((SELECT   
               ',' +item_id  
            FROM @tblName Where A.[user] = [user]
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''   
        )
FROM @tblName A GROUP by [user]
```